# how can i select the wordpress stylesheet

Tags: wordpress

hello im using redux framework , i have a probleme
this is my code

```
array(
'id'=>'stylesheet',
'type' => 'select',
'title' => __('Theme Stylesheet', 'redux-framework-demo'),
'subtitle' => __('Select your themes alternative color scheme.', 'redux-enter code     here`demo'),
'options' => array('style.css'=>'Light', 'dark.css'=>'Dark'),
'default' => 'light',
),
```

i created dark.css file , but when I'm selecting the dark style from the option panel , nothing changes
well i read some docs to understand how it works, now i have this variable :

```
 <?php echo $hours['stylesheet']; ?>
```

i pasted it on calling code of style like this

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blablabla/<?php echo   $hours['stylesheet'];?>"type="text/css"/>
```

but nothing it changes ! .

i know its a Stupid question :/ i hope there is one who can help me :)

Comment: Where is $hours defined?

Comment: What is the return from print_r($hours); ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the redux but this code help you?

```
$hours = array(
'id'=>'stylesheet',
'type' => 'select',
'title' => __('Theme Stylesheet', 'redux-framework-demo'),
'subtitle' => __('Select your themes alternative color scheme.', 'redux-enter code     here`demo'),
'options' => array('style.css'=>'Light', 'dark.css'=>'Dark'),
'default' => 'light',
)
```

and...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blablabla/<?php echo $hours['options'][1];?>"type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lead dev at redux here. Looks like you're not declaring your global variable before you try to use it.

Use either:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blablabla/<?php global $hours; echo $hours['stylesheet'];?>"type="text/css"/>
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blablabla/<?php echo $GLOBALS['hours']['stylesheet'];?>"type="text/css"/>
```